# Comparing values in two columns in same table and creating new column

Tags: sql, oracle

This must be pretty easy query but for some reason I am not able to get the right query. I am using Oracle SQL. I have a table which has details of peoples who send gifts to each other, I want to track people who has exchanged the gift with eachother. I  am trying to compare two columns in the same table.

Table:

```
SenderId  |  Sender    |  ReceiverId  |  Receiver  |
   1      |  Christen  |       30     |  Sharyn    |
   2      |  Will      |      5       |  Madeline  |
   7      |  Kim       |      25      |  Lee       |
  30      |  Sharyn    |       1      |  Christen  |
  25      |  Lee       |      7       |   Kim      |
```

Expected Result Table:

```
 Sender    |  Receiver  | Exchanged_Gift
 Christen  |  Sharyn    |      1
 Will      |  Madeline  |      0
 Kim       |  Lee       |      1
```

Since there are two groups of people who have exchanged the gift, the new column will have 1 if they exchanged the gift else 0.

1st Group --- Christen and Sharyn have both exchanged the gift.
2nd Group --- Kim and Lee have also exchanged the gift.

Comment: Thank you both @Gordon Linoff and Tejash, both the queries worked for me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky because when there is only one row, then you want to keep the original ordering.  One method is aggregation with `union all`:

```
select least(sender, receiver) as sender, greatest(sender, receiver) as receiver, 1 as exchanged
from t
group by least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver)
having count(*) = 2
union all
select sender, receiver, 0
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.receiver = t.sender and t2.sender = t2.receiver
                 );
```

Comment: I am accepting Tejash response as the solution for my question but my table got evolved with an addtional Date column, with date column being included Tejash solution is giving duplicate values but @Gordon Linoff would give the correct values.

Comment: Hey @Gordon Linoff,  it would be helpful if you can explain me the logic of this statement
select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.receiver = t.sender and t2.sender = t2.receiver
specifically the where clause, thanks in advance

Comment: @Nik . . . That solution does not return Will/Madeleine, so I don't see how it answers the question you asked.

Comment: will check once again, just be sure because I had provided the test data so will check and update, I am still trying to figure out the inner query that provided

Comment: checked, yes you are right about the missing row.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `least` and `greatest` function as follows:

```
Select case when count(1) = 1 then max(sender) else least(sender,receiver) end as sender, 
       case when count(1) = 1 then max(receiver) else greatest(sender,receiver) end as receiver,
       count(1) - 1 as exchanged_gifts
  From your_table
Group by least(sender,receiver), greatest(sender,receiver)
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to fulfill the requirement of single row and swapping should not happen between sender and receiver name.