# SQL query to extract matching diagonal pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I have a database table (`mytable`) with 2 columns `x` and `y` as shown below, from which I intend to extract rows with matching diagonal pairs of (x,y) and (y,x) e.g., 4 21 and 21 4

```
x  y
86 86
27 27
45 45
95 95
11 11
18 8
85 85
2 2
77 77
91 91
15 15
84 84
51 51
32 32
35 35
8 8
92 92
67 67
62 62
33 33
13 13
15 11
18 18
3 3
38 38
80 80
34 34
6 6
72 72
14 12
44 44
4 22
90 90
47 47
78 78
23 3
42 42
56 56
79 79
55 55
65 65
17 17
64 64
4 4
28 28
19 19
17 9
36 36
25 25
81 81
60 60
48 48
5 5
88 88
7 19
21 21
29 29
52 52
9 17
9 9
13 13
16 10
1 1
31 31
46 46
7 7
58 58
23 23
87 87
83 83
66 66
93 93
24 2
98 98
53 53
20 6
61 61
20 20
96 96
99 99
73 73
2 24
14 14
71 71
5 21
22 4
75 75
6 20
97 97
41 41
26 26
22 22
8 18
74 74
40 40
21 5
94 94
76 76
49 49
11 15
59 59
89 89
68 68
24 24
37 37
12 12
63 63
43 43
16 16
100 100
39 39
25 1
69 69
54 54
50 50
30 30
10 10
```

I have tried the accepted code on StackOverflow here ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076598/comparing-values-in-two-columns-in-same-table-and-creating-new-column)) on my **mytable** which gives me the expected results on an Oracle database.

```
select least(x, y) as x, greatest(x, y) as y
from mytable
group by least(x, y), greatest(x, y)
having count(*) = 2
union all
select x, y
from mytable
where not exists (select 1 from mytable mytable2 where mytable2.y = mytable.x and mytable2.x = mytable2.y)
order by x asc;
```

Now I need to execute the same query on a SQL Server database but according to my understanding SQL Server does not support the `least` and `greatest` functions. I have tried to use case expressions, for instance for the first part of the SQL query on the link provided, I am considering the below but so far I cannot replicate similar results:

```
select x,y,z
from (
select x, y,
case 
    when (x < y) then x
    when (y > x) then y
end as z
from mytable
group by x, y
) as t
```

Any suggestions on what I need to consider to complete the query in SQL Server database, so that I produce the final output as below?

It would also be great if somebody has an idea on how I can use SQL's `lag()` function to assist me in achieving the same result. For instance I am trying something like below.

```
with t1 as (
  select x as x1, y as y1, lag(x,1) over(order by x asc) as z1
  from mytable
), t2 as (
  select x as x2, y as y2, lag(y,1) over(order by x asc) as z2
  from mytable
)
select t1.*,t2.*
from t1
full outer join t2 on t1.x1 = t2.x2
```

**Expected output**:

```
x y
2 24
4 22
5 21
6 20
8 18
9 17
11 15
13 13
```

Comment: Note: the functions are supported, but starting from SQL Server 2022.

Comment: What is the point of UNION ALL in the 1st query for Oracle?

Comment: @forpas...just checked and it seems the union all is unnecessary. Thanks

Comment: @ Zhorov...noted thanks a lot, seeking a solution that runs on lower versions of SQL Server at least for now before upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` is to use `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x < y THEN x ELSE y END AS x, 
       CASE WHEN x > y THEN x ELSE y END AS y
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN x < y THEN x ELSE y END, 
         CASE WHEN x > y THEN x ELSE y END
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- change to COUNT(*) > 1 if each combination may exist more than twice
ORDER BY x, y;
```

The above query will return a row for a combination of `(x, y)` that exists twice even if `(y, x)` does not exist.

If this is not what you want, use a self join and `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable t2
ON t2.x = t1.y AND t2.y = t1.x
WHERE t1.x < t1.y
UNION ALL
SELECT x, y
FROM mytable
WHERE x = y
GROUP BY x, y
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY x, y;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZxocopOw).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both solutions work for me.